# form input for number to write to SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

How to put default prefix at form and write it to sql table

Here's the code

```
<form method="post" action="blablabla.php">
        <p><input type="text" name="full_name" value="" placeholder="member  Fullname" required></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="msisdn" value="" placeholder="please use prefix 42" required></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
</form>
```

i'd like to use the second form with required prefix... so it will post/submit to sql table

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.  You haven't provided anywhere near enough information.  The question is also very broad. "How to write to sql table".  This is something that whole libraries are dedicated to.  Please clarify what you are asking and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why not append 42 after posting? like this `$msisdn = "42".$_POST['msisdn'];`

Comment: @VijayaSankarN : i am sorry, can you give me the sample ? or where i must put it ? inside form or outside ?

Comment: In blablabla.php where you have query in SQL

Comment: i see, i will try in few hours ( right now i am not at my computer, ) - status - hold

Comment: that would be the solution thank you @VijayaSankarN

Comment: @LukePark : please vote up . i can not post new question

Comment: @jhondoelearning The questions quality is still extremely poor.  I can't vote up unless it is edited.

Comment: yes, maybe it poor, i am new here, can you help me which part should be edited ? @LukePark

Comment: @jhondoelearning Read my first comment.  Additionally read the "How do I ask a good question?" article on SO.

Comment: @LukePark : i have already change the title, just like your first comment

Comment: @jhondoelearning My first comment doesn't ask to change the title.  Please just read the How to ask guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better append 42 after posting like this

```
$msisdn = "42".$_POST['msisdn'];
```

in blablabla.php where you have query in SQL.

(This has been answered in comments)

In addition, if it is necessary for visibility purpose, you can  add a label before the input with 42 as text.